I'm having trouble injecting my service class into my component constructor - Angular 18
I'm using Angular 18 and I'm trying to work through a tutorial which is geared for a much older version.
Here is my Service class:
export class ProductsService
{ 
    getProducts() : string[] 
    { 
        return ["Learning Angular","Pro TypeScript","ASP.NET"]; 
    } 
}

I'm trying to use this from my Component class by injecting it into the constructor. As such:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrl: './products.component.css',
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: string[] = [];

  constructor(ps: ProductsService)
  { 
    this.products = ps.getProducts(); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
  }
}

The error I'm getting is: NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for ProductsService!
Now the documentation states that I need to add some code into app.module.ts:

But in this version of Angular, there is no such file as app.module.ts. So where am I supposed to define this dependency?

I found the answer while I was typing up the question. I searched for the term "providers" and I found it in app.config.ts. I modified this to add ProductsService to the array of providers.
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsService } from './products/products.service';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers:
    [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
      provideRouter(routes), 
      ProductsService
    ]
};

This solves the problem and the feature works!
Alternatively, you can provide the DI support directly in the definition of the service itself: (Hat tip to Matthieu Riegler, who suggested this in the comment below.)
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ProductsService
{ 
    getProducts() : string[] 
    { 
        return ["Learning Angular","Pro TypeScript","ASP.NET"]; 
    } 
}

However, this brings up a follow up question. Since this dependency is now scoped to the entire application, why should I not just make the getProducts method static and then call it from the type of ProductsService without requiring an instance of the class to be injected into the constructor?

You should add provideIn: 'root' to your service instead.

@MatthieuRiegler Thank you! I found an example of that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518881/angular-providers-or-providedin. I used that approach and it works! Seems cleaner as we don't need to bulk up app.config.ts with the definition of all service providers.

@YossiG. To answer your question about why not create a class with static method - technically you could do that. But there are few reasons why you shouldn't - first it's then harder to write unit tests for component that uses the service - if service is injected, then you can easily mock it in test. If it's static method, you need to use real service logic in the test. Another reason is that your service might have dependencies on other services - then it's much easier to inject them if your service is also injectable
